# How can i make screen session as 'Dead'?

Tags: linux, screen

I need to make situation like screen session as 'Dead'?

However, i don't know how to make the session status as 'Dead'

Could you give some advises to make this status??

Answer (score 0):

Open the Linux terminal and execute the following command:

`screen -X -S [session number] quit`

Use the following command to remove a screen session:

`screen -X -S <screen_id> kill`

Comment: Those commands just remove the session, not making session as 'Dead'

Answer (score 0):

`respawn-pane -kt sth:0.0 true`

if you want to kill all panes in a window you can just do

`respawn-window -kt sth:0 true`